# What is difference between FragmentActivity and Activity?

Tags: android

I have used it in my basic code replace activity by fragment activity,but i have not got any kind of error.Application has working.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in the documentation:

FragmentActivity

> Base class for activities that want to use the support-based Fragment
>   and Loader APIs.

Activity

> An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with setContentView(View). While activities are often presented to the user as full-screen windows, they can also be used in other ways: as floating windows (via a theme with windowIsFloating set) or embedded inside of another activity (using ActivityGroup)

Can see more  at : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

A fragment activity can contain [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) (as it's name implies). It's the support version of activities for older APIs, which want to use fragments.

Answer (score 0):

A [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) , introduced in `Android 3.0 HoneyComb` is a portion of a user interface inside an activity. You can have many fragments in you UI.

[FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) is the base class you must extend in order to use fragments with the support library.

Answer (score 0):

The nuance here is that an `Activity` can use `Fragment`s from the native SDK (as long as you are targeting API 11+), while a `FragmentActivity` can use `Fragment`s from the support library.

So, assuming API 11+, if you are using `android.app.Fragment`s in your app, you can use `Activity`, but if you are using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`s in your app, then you must use `FragmentActivity`.